# Elasticsearch: Remove Duplicate Records from Index Documents

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

Here is my JDBC river commands for fetching all records from database.

```
localhost:9200/_river/my_update_river/_meta
{
  "type" : "jdbc",
   "jdbc" : {
     "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/admin",
      "user" : "root",
      "password" : "",
      "poll" : "6s",
      "index" : "updateauto",
      "type" : "users",
      "schedule":"0/10 * * ? * *",
      "strategy" : "simple",
      "sql" : "select * from users"
    }
 }
```

When I run this command: I have two problems:

1. Duplicate Records
2. And when I add new records in database its not updating index documents but search it by

   {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "term": { "Name": "testing" }
           }
       }
      }
    }

Here's my result.

```
   {
     "took" : 4,
     "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
      "failed" : 0
   },
     "hits" : {
     "total" : 37551,
      "max_score" : 1.0,
      "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "updateauto",
      "_type" : "users",
      "_id" : "AUvjnNHmMKBTPrby96Jg",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"ID":23,"Name":"Abudul  Rafay","Email":"a","Password":"afasd"}
}, {
      "_index" : "updateauto",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "AUvjnNHnMKBTPrby96Jk",
    "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":25,"Name":"r rafay ","Email":"r rafay","Password":"r rafay"}
}, {
      "_index" : "updateauto",
      "_type" : "users",
       "_id" : "AUvjngk0MKBTPrby96Ka",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"ID":23,"Name":"Abudul Rafay","Email":"a","Password":"afasd"}
}, {
     "_index" : "updateauto",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "AUvjngk0MKBTPrby96Kf",
     " _score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":24,"Name":"rafay","Email":"hello","Password":"fasfas"}
}, {
      "_index" : "updateauto",
      "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "AUvjnjA0MKBTPrby96Kh",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":23,"Name":"Abudul Rafay","Email":"a","Password":"afasd"}
}, {
     "_index" : "updateauto",
      "_type" : "users",
    "_id" : "AUvjnjA0MKBTPrby96Km",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":24,"Name":"rafay","Email":"hello","Password":"fasfas"}
},  {
    "_index" : "updateauto",
    "_type" : "users",
    "_id" : "AUvjnZP0MKBTPrby96KD",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":24,"Name":"rafay","Email":"hello","Password":"fasfas"}
}, {
    "_index" : "updateauto",
    "_type" : "users",
    "_id" : "AUvjnPe-MKBTPrby96Jq",
   "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":25,"Name":"r rafay ","Email":"r rafay","Password":"r rafay"}
}, {
    "_index" : "updateauto",
    "_type" : "users",
   "_id" : "AUvjnR7NMKBTPrby96Ju",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":26,"Name":"New User","Email":"New","Password":"new"}
}, {
    "_index" : "updateauto",
    "_type" : "users",
    "_id" : "AUvjnbuLMKBTPrby96KO",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":26,"Name":"New User","Email":"New","Password":"new"}
    } ]
   }
 }
```

I want result without duplicate records and also auto updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite catch your second question but considering the duplicate issue here is what you need to do :

You'll need to specify the id of document from within the river definition as followed :

```
"sql" : "select *, ID as _id from user"
```

This way, the river will just write each user concedering it's id.

Comment: Oh thanks.. its working.. My second question was when i add new record in database then index is not updating automatically but now its all right.Now I just want to ask one more question that how can i search data by one word like ' { "query" : { "filter" : { "term" : { "Name" : "a" } } } }' and get all records that contains word 'a'.

Comment: Lol it's a one question post man! be cool, and try to reformulate your last question because I don't actually get what you are asking!